# Tentando imprimir a soma total de todos os valores dentro da lista?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando imprimir a soma total de todos os valores dentro da lista, porém o que meu código faz é somar o primeiro elemento com o primeiro elemento e dar o resultado, depois o segundo elemento com o segundo elemento e assim por diante. Segue código:

```
const valor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i in valor){    
    i++;
    let soma = i + i;
    console.log(`i = ${soma}`);
}
```

Comment: me desculpem por fazer um tópico tão mal feito, é a primeira vez que publico aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há muitos problemas no seu código e um deles, é que você utiliza o operador `in` ao invés do operador `of`. O [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) é um operador que irá percorrer os atributos de um objeto e não seu valores.

```
const objeto = {nome: "lucas", idade: 32};

for (let chave in objeto) {
    console.log(chave);         // Saída: nome; idade
}
```

Por outro lado, o [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) irá percorrer cada elemento do seu Array. Veja abaixo o que você na verdade estava percorrendo com seu código:

```js
const valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i in valores){
    console.log(i);
}
```

Um outro problema no seu código, é que você não estava incrementando a variável `soma`. A cada loop que o laço `for` fazia, você apenas atribuía um valor de `i + i`, ou seja, o que acontecia era isso:

```
soma = 1 + 1;
soma = 2 + 2;
soma = 3 + 3;
// ...
```

Para corrigir o seu código, você deve utilizar o operador `of` para percorrer os elementos do Array e depois você deve incrementar à variável `soma` o valor de `i`, dessa foma:

```js
const valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var soma = 0;

for (let i of valores){    
    soma += i; // O operador "+=" equivale a fazer "soma = soma + 1" 
}

console.log(`Soma de ${valores.join(" + ")} = ` + soma);
```

Além de utilizar o laço `for`, você pode utilizar o método [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para percorrer os elementos do Array e realizar alguma ação com eles utilizando um dado auxiliar que será modificado ao longo do processo e por fim retornado.

Ficou um pouco difícil a explicação ? Então veja o método funcionando na prática.

```js
const valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// O número 0 na chamada do método é o valor inicial que será manipulado.

var resultado = valores.reduce(function(valor, valores_somados){
    return valores_somados + valor; 
}, 0);  

console.log(resultado);

// É possível também reduzir o código acima utilizando arrow function.

var resultado = valores.reduce((valor, soma) => valor + soma, 0);
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

Na sua pergunta o seu código tem bastante problemas um deles é colocar a `soma` para imprimir dentro do `for`, nesse momento a variável `soma` só deveria receber a soma do próximo elemento com a `soma` e fora desse `for` mostrar, outro problema é que usou o `for` errado, nesse caso deveria ser o `for..of` que realmente pega o valor de cada posição.

Alguns exemplos básicos:

---

Para somar elementos de um `array` em `Javascript`:

Utilizando [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```js
const valor = [1,2,3,4,5];
let soma = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < valor.length; i++){    
    soma = valor[i] + soma;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = soma;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Utilizando [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
const valor = [1,2,3,4,5];
let soma = 0;
for (let i of valor){    
    soma = soma + i;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = soma;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Utilizando [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const valor = [1,2,3,4,5];

const soma = valor.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = soma;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, você ajudou demais!